# NotImplementedError: Pre-trained Graph Output -> New Layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am working on feeding some outputs of a pre-trained graph into some additional layers in Tensorflow. Here is a walkthrough of some of my code:

First, I define a new tf.Graph(), and load in the pre-trained model.

```
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
    with detection_graph.as_default():
        od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        with tf.gfile.GFile('./mobilenetssd/frozen_inference_graph.pb', 'rb') as fid:
            serialized_graph = fid.read()
            od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
            tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
```

Fetching input/output tensors of the loaded graph, defining placeholders, adding some ops.

```
            image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
            output_matrix = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('concat:0')
            labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

            # Adding operations
            outmat_sq = tf.squeeze(output_matrix)
            logits_max = tf.squeeze(tf.math.reduce_max(outmat_sq, reduction_indices=[0]))
            logits_mean = tf.squeeze(tf.math.reduce_mean(outmat_sq, reduction_indices=[0]))
            logodds = tf.concat([logits_max, logits_mean], 0)
            logodds = tf.expand_dims(logodds, 0)
            logodds.set_shape([None, 1204])
```

Defining the new layers, setting up optimizer to train new layers.

```
            hidden = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=logodds, num_outputs=500, activation_fn=tf.nn.tanh)
            out = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=hidden, num_outputs=1, activation_fn=tf.nn.sigmoid)

            # Define Loss, Training, and Accuracy 
            loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=out, labels=labels))
            training_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-6).minimize(loss, var_list=[hidden, out])
            correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.round(out), labels)
            accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
```

After running this code, I am getting a **NotImplementedError:('Trying to update a Tensor ', tf.Tensor 'fully_connected/Tanh:0' shape=(?, 500) dtype=float32)** error. This seems to be a problem with "linking" the two parts of the model together. Do I need to pass the output of the first graph into some tf.Variable and then pass that into the subsequent layers? Also, I am using TF 1.10.

Any insight on this would be appreciated!